# parsing json in ruby for sorting, filtering, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I'm using koala to get the following JSON object from facebook:

```
@friends = [{"name"=>"Jolie Chide", "gender"=>"female", "id"=>"4216323"},
            {"name"=>"Seth Spring", "gender"=>"male", "id"=>"3429277"}]
```

What I would like to do is the following:

```
<% @friends.where(:gender == "female").order("@friends['name'] ASC").each do |friend| %>
  <%= friend['name'] %>
<% end %>
```

**As you know, this will not work.** I'm used to standard Ruby objects and not with the JSON above. If anyone has any advice on how to get the above to work, even if it means converting the data from JSON, that would be great. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have there is not JSON, but an `Array` of `Hash`es. These are built-in Ruby collections, rather than ActiveRecord relations, and they have methods like `select` and `sort_by` that allow you to do the kinds of things you want to do there. You should become familiar with these classes and their methods, because they're much more basic to Ruby than the ActiveRecord stuff is, and they are used everywhere.

The operation you want can be expressed as follows:

```
@friends.select {|hash| hash['gender'] == 'female'}.sort_by {|hash| hash['name']}
```

Comment: Not necessarily incorrect, but the array is not being sorted by name. It is selecting only the female genders but when printed, it remains in the existing order.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to grab the `json data` and assign to instance variable and use following .

**Ascending**

```
@graph = @abc.sort_by { |hash| hash['created_time'] }
```

or

```
graph = abc.sort_by { |hash| hash['created_time'] }
```

**Descending**

```
@graph = @abc.sort_by { |hash| hash['created_time'] }.reverse!
```

or

```
graph = abc.sort_by { |hash| hash['created_time'] }.reverse!
```